# find item in list of class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have class called GroupSelect and made a collection `List(Of GroupSelect)()`.

Now I need find to RowNo = 4 in `List(Of GroupSelect)()` and get GroupSelect object.

```
Public Class GroupSelect
Public Property RowNo() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_RowNo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_RowNo = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_RowNo As Integer
Public Property GroupNo() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_GroupNo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_GroupNo = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_GroupNo As Integer
```

End Class

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using System.Linq and then it's as easy as:

```
list.FirstOrDefault(Function(item) item.RowNo = 4)
```

Or if you aren't familiar with the predicate syntax

```
(From item In list Where item.RowNo = 4 Select Item).FirstOrDefault())
```

**EDIT**: Changed to VB syntax, which is notepad-compiled :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Linq with less code, but here is a more n00bish / old fashioned way of doing it if you don't want to mess Linq...

```
Private Function GetRowNumberFour(ByVal lstYourList as List(of GroupSelect)) As GroupSelect

   For each obj as GroupSelect In lstYourList

      If obj.RowNo = 4 Then

         Return obj

      End If

   Next

End Function
```

This function will return the GroupSelect object that you want.